# How to extract values from Response Headers and make assertations using Rest Assured?

Tags: cookies, response, setcookie, rest-assured, response-headers

I want to extract values from Response Headers and store them as Strings and eventually make assertions with certain values.

From the following Response Header I want to extract `* Set-Cookie:id=xxxxxx-xxxxxxx-xxxxxx;` and store it.

I am using Rest Assured. Thanks!

```
Response Headers 
* Cache-Control:no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
* Connection:keep-alive
* Content-Length:108
* Content-Type:image/png
* Date:Wed, 22 Mar 2017 13:19:51 GMT
* Expires:0
* Pragma:no-cache
* Server:nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)
* Set-Cookie: AWSELB=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX;PATH=/;DOMAIN=.xxxx.xxxxx.com;MAX-AGE=3600;VERSION=1
* Set-Cookie:id=xxxxxx-xxxxxxx-xxxxxx; Version=1; Path=/; Domain=.xxxx.xxxxx.com; Max-Age=157680000
* Set-Cookie:Session=xxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxx; Version=1; Path=/; Domain=.xxxxx.xxxxxx.com; Max-Age=3600
* X-Powered-By:Xxxxxxxx/1
* X-Robots-Tag:noindex, nofollow
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slightly adapted from the doc : https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#headers-cookies-status-etc

**Cookies**

To get all values for a cookie you need to first get the Cookies object from the Response object. From the Cookies instance you can get all values using the Cookies.getValues() method which returns a List with all cookie values.

Simple values as String :

```
import io.restassured.http.Cookie;
import io.restassured.http.Cookies;
import io.restassured.response.Response;

Map<String, String> allCookies = get("https://www.stackoverflow.com").getCookies();

List<String> myCookieValues = allCookies.getValues("myCookieName");
```

To get all fields from cookies, you need detailed cookies :

```
Cookies allDetailedCookies = get("https://www.stackoverflow.com").getDetailedCookies();

Cookie myCookie = allDetailedCookies.get("myCookieName");
myCookie.getValue();
myCookie.getDomain();
myCookie.getExpiryDate();
myCookie.getMaxAge();
...
```

If multi valued cookie :

```
List<Cookie> myCookies = allDetailedCookies.getList("myCookieNAme");
```

You can assert on cookie with hamcrest matchers :

```
import static io.restassured.RestAssured.when;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.hasValue;

when()
    .get("https://www.stackoverflow.com").
then()
    .cookie("myCookieName", hasValue("value"));
```

Doc recommends imports from :

```
io.restassured.RestAssured.*
io.restassured.matcher.RestAssuredMatchers.*
org.hamcrest.Matchers.*
```